What is the meaning of $H^{[0,1]}$ in the upcrossing inequality?
I am trying to understand the following example that was meant to introduce the upcrossing inequality.
The example is below.
My question is, what is the meaning of $H^{[0,1]}$, there was no mention in the text I was reading. So maybe someone who already knows this topic could help me.
(I am sorry if this is a rather boring non-mathematical question.)
Suppose $(M_n)_n$ is a stochastic process. Consider the "buy low, sell high" strategy. Think of $M_n$ as the stock price on day $n$ (for simplicity we will also allow negative stock value). Everytime when $M_n$ falls below $0$, we buy a share. As soon as $M_n$ rises above $1$, we sell the stock. Let $(H_n)_n$ denote this strategy. Every upcrossing of the interval $[0,1] $ yields $1$ Dollar profit.
Let us denote the number of upcrossings up to the time $n$ as $U_n^{[0,1]}$. In fact our profit $(H^{[0,1]} M)_n$ up to the time $n$ is not greater than $U_n^{[0,1]}$. The reason for that is that $M_n$ after bought at value $0$ still can continue to loose value.
But the following inequality holds:
$U_n^{[0,1]} \leq (H^{[0,1]} M)+(M_n)_{-}$, where $(M_n)_{-}$ denotes the negative part of $M_n$.

$(H^{[0,1]}M)_n$ denotes your total profit up to day $n$ by following the strategy.

@user806050 thank you
